# Minimum of pairs between two lists, is there a quicker way?

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension

I have two (very long) lists. I want to find the sum of the minimum of each pair in the list. Eg, if

```py
X = [2,3,4]
Y = [5,4,2]
```

then, the sum would be `2+3+2 = 7`.
At the moment, I'm doing this by zipping the lists and using a list comprehension. My lists are X and Y:

```py
mins = [min(x,y) for x,y in zip(X,Y)]
summed_mins = sum(mins)
```

This is causing serious runtime issues in my program. Is there a faster way to do this? List comprehensions are the fastest that I know of.

Comment: looks like your code is working fine, without any error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Python generators** and the built-in **map** function to avoid the creation of the list, but this will probably be just slightly faster (thanks to [Veedrac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763356/veedrac)):

```py
summed_mins = sum(map(min, x, y))
```

Alternatively, you can use **Numpy**. Here is how:

```py
summed_mins = np.stack((X, Y)).min(axis=0).sum()
```

If you can store the input list directly as Numpy arrays, this can be much faster.
If you can even store it directly in a 2D Numpy array, you don't need the `np.stack` call resulting in a much faster code.
If you cannot store/create the input directly as Numpy arrays, you can create the Numpy arrays on the fly quickly by specifying the data type (assuming you are sure the list contain small integers). Here is an example:

```py
summed_mins = np.stack((np.array(a, np.int64), np.array(b, np.int64))).min(axis=0)
```

Comment: `sum(map(min, x, y))`

Comment: Note that Numpy will truncate to 64 bits unless you do `numpy.array((x, y), dtype=object)`.

Comment: I see that you are also a fan of performance in python, too bad the parallelism side of this language

Comment: @dreamcrash Yes, I totally agree, but there is still a big room for improvement in existing codes. It is funny to speed up codes by a factor sometimes up to 100~1000 just by using Numpy/Numba and few algorithm fixes ;) .

Comment: @JérômeRichard I now the felling :) you get a lot of those when you are using GPUs albeit normally this means that the original code was not code enough hence the reason why one ca optimized so much